# google's newborn app "Spaces" API

Tags: api, google-api-client

Today I came up with some idea about googles new product "Spaces". I have searched a lot but couldn't find any sign that this app has API.

Do you have any information about this topic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there aren't any API available for Spaces.

You can check all available products from Google here: https://developers.google.com/products/